# What is the correct syntax to pass a base64 instead of a url to Microsoft Azure Computer vision API using Ruby

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-hub

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({

    'language' => 'unk',
    'detectOrientation ' => 'true'
})

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

request['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'

request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = 'MY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'

request.body = "raw_image_binary"


response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    http.request(request)
end

puts response.body
```

I got this as a response.

{"code":"InvalidImageFormat","requestId":"3aee7147-2acc-4f64-b1c6-8453815eda38","message":"Input data is not a valid image."}

HELP!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass an image file to Azure Computer Vision API via `application/octet-stream` content type in Ruby, so you need to pass binary image data to `response.body`, not pass the base64 string of an image.

Please use the code below instead of the current one to make it works.

```
# Supported image formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP.
request.body = File.binread("<your image file name>") 
# Or `request.body = File.open("<your image file name>") {|io| io.read}` also works
```